Cannot pass some of the tests on Scala in IDE
So I have basic game, coded on scala, its a game where player can move: up, down, right and left in order to collect coins on board that is 10x10 size.
def checkCoins(): Unit = {
    if (math.abs(positionX - saveX) >= 3 && math.abs(positionY - saveY) >= 3) {
      val xMin = math.min(positionX, saveX)
      val xMax = math.max(positionX, saveX)
      val yMin = math.min(positionY, saveY)
      val yMax = math.max(positionY, saveY)

      for (x <- xMin to xMax; y <- yMin to yMax if board(x)(y) > 0) {
        points += board(x)(y)
        board(x)(y) = -1
      }
      saveX = -1
      saveY = -1
    }
  }

and the code for saving player position:
def save(): Unit = {
    /* This method is already implemented. You should not change it */
    saveX = positionX
    saveY = positionY
  }

The problem occuring when I run the tests in IDE using Junit testing. The position of player in method checkCoins() should reset the player position to -1,-1 in case the condition is met but it actually doesnt do it. I dont really understand what is the problem with the rewriting the position by calling a method save() and input -1,-1. The thing is that the tests, cannot be changed or even slightly altered only the code and the NOT implemented methods (the code that is implemented is being mentioned in comments).
I tried rewriting logic of method checkCoins() and manually input the data. Also I tried to search for another methods of doing the checkCoins() but they made everything even worse. Image of testing is attached. Testing
the first method of checkCoins() was:
val xMin = math.min(positionX, saveX)
  val xMax = math.max(positionX, saveX)
  val yMin = math.min(positionY, saveY)
  val yMax = math.max(positionY, saveY)

  if ((xMax - xMin + 1) * (yMax - yMin + 1) >= 9) {
    for (x <- xMin to xMax; y <- yMin to yMax if board(x)(y) > 0) {
      points += board(x)(y)
      board(x)(y) = -1
    }
    saveX = -1
    saveY = -1
  }


If the position should be updated in checkCoins, it seems rather strange (or poor naming) to be updating saveX/saveY (especially in view that save will clobber those variables while preserving the position variables)

The comment in save implies that this is an exercise, and that the exercise requires you to use mutable values. Using mutable values is not functional and  is almost always a bad idea, so I suggest finding some exercises in functional programming instead.
